# How to set td color on hover in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By default in `Twitter Bootstrap` tables with class `.table-hover` uses style:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > td:first-child {
    background-color: inherit !important;
}
```

That only the first `td` of `tr` would not be changed on `hover` ?

Comment: do you want all the td to be hovered with a color but not the very first td?

Comment: @Shanaka yes, you right

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Bootstraps colors the background of the `tr`. In order to override that you'll need to color the `td` with the background-color of the page.

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover td:first-child {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Using a transparent background won't work, because the background-color of the `tr` lies underneath it.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/40oeL57b/1/).

<strike>You could use the `nth-child` selector, to select all cells in the row, but the first:</strike>

```
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover td:nth-child(n+2) {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/40oeL57b/)

Comment: As I was saying I'm using `bootstrap`, which on `hover` automatically adds  `#f5f5f5` to all elements. I need to do somehow that first td would used not change the default color.

Comment: Yes, @Leo, if the background color of the table (or any parent) is grey, or blue, or green, or whatever, the `#fff` needs to be changed to that color. Like I explained, the problem is that Bootstraps colors the rows and not the cells.

Comment: @ LinkenTED, yup i have read that but then its not solution, its like changing the colour according to background..m searching for solution and if i will found, sure will share with you..:)

Comment: @Leo, it's the closest thing to a solution. Believe me, there is no other way. (Or you need to be able to change Bootstrap :)  )

Comment: @ LinkinTED, yes i respect you and your solution but nothing is impossible so let me try..may be there will be way..:)